# Separation of interface and implementation in api

Tags: java, api

I am writing a framework built around `jUnit` for scripting tests in in Java.

It's task based, and each task is executed in sequence. Here is a simplified view:

The interface which all task uses looks like

```
public interface Task {
    void run(Callback callback);
}
```

with the `Callback` interface providing the task with a way to tell the executer that it has finished.

```
public interface Callback {
    void done();
    void failed(String wtf);
}
```

I'm also providing the user with an interface to the executor, to an external (physical) interface and to a settings class. I call this the Runtime Environment, and is implemented abstractly:

```
public abstract class RuntimeEnvironment {
    void execute(Task task) { ... }
    void schedule(Task task, long delay) { ... }
    SomeExternalInterface external();
    Settings settings();
}
```

where `SomeExternalInterface` and `Settings` are interfaces both used by the framework and the implementing user.

The framework might use members like `threadPoolSize` from `Settings`, and 'intialize()' and 'cleanUp()' from `SomeExternalInterface`

The way this class is passed to tasks are currently through the constructor of the implementing task class. I don't like this. It makes for an ambiguous api compared to having the RuntimeEnvironment specified in the `Task` interface

Why not add it to the task interface you ask? Like

```
public interface Task {
    void run(Callback callback, RuntimeEnvironment runtime);
}
```

becouse, running `runtime.settings().getThreadPoolSize()` is fine (since its specifed in the interface), but what if the user wants to be able to get `runtime.settings().getWonkyTimeUnit()` or `runtime.external().attemptToDefuseImminentExplotion()` which he or her specified in the implementation of the respective interfaces? runtime.settings() returns the interface, not the implementing class.

So ...

### How do I allow the api-user to specify hes (or hers) own implementation without compromising the generalization and the unambiguousness of the api?

Answer (score 1):

You could allow custom settings to be get / set using strings: `runtime.settings().set("wonky_time_unit");` so that users can add as many properties as they want and they will be available through the settings interface: `runtime.settings().set("attemptToDefuseImminentExplotion") = true;`.

Answer (score 1):

If its all about the settings or better the configuration, you could have a look how Apache Hadoop is handling such circumstances. They have a `Context` where they store a `Configuration` class. Same like your `RuntimeEnvironment` and `Settings`. Internally the `Configuration` class uses a `Map` with all the configurations and you can access them via the keys you gave your specific configuration. See: [Hadoop Configuration](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the user can have his own implementations/interfaces for Settings and External you must allow that. Your api must have the possibility to set/define the type.

```
public abstract class RuntimeEnvironment<E, S extends Settings> {
...

   E external();
   S settings();
...
}
```

is one possibility. The user can implement the abstract class and return his own types.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this approach too, but decided that there was a value in keeping it simple. The api needs to be used by people not so profisient in Java and OO methods. I might give it another go, still.